# How can I divide the sum of my array elements with their amount?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
double array_of_grades[] = new double[number_of_subjects];
double average;

for(int i=0; i < number_of_subjects; i++) {
    array_of_grades[i]=array[i].getGrade();
}
```

`array[]` is an array of objects, which contains all the information about each subject. Each subject has 1 grade. I want to get the average grade of all the subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the sum:

```
double sum = 0;
for (double grade : array_of_grades) 
    sum += grade;
```

Then calculate the average:

```
average = 1.0d * sum / array_of_grades.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `stream` from directly beginning your process from your `array`

```
double avg = Stream.of(array)
                   .mapToDouble(x -> x.getGrade())
                   .average()
                   .getAsDouble();
```